# Validating File using React-Hook-Form and Yup (<x> must be a `object` type, but the final value was: `null`)

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I'm working on a simple file upload form using react-hook-form and I need to validate that a file has been selected for upload. Using yup for validation. I realize there are other questions on this topic but I was unable to find a working solution.

My file upload component is based (almost 100% the same) on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68519175/1769106. It seems to be working just fine, if I disable validation the file is uploaded correctly.

The issue I'm facing is when validating whether a file has been selected
I get the error `file must be a 'object' type, but the final value was: 'null'`.

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-cache-x4hms3?file=/src/form.tsx) showing the problem. I added some prints showing the contents of the "file" form property and its type (which shows as object)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use schema validation below, it should work as expected.

```
 const fileFormSchema = yup.object().shape({
    file: mixed()
          .test("required", "You need to provide a file", (file) => {
            // return file && file.size <-- u can use this if you don't want to allow empty files to be uploaded;
            if (file) return true;
            return false;
          })
          .test("fileSize", "The file is too large", (file) => {
            //if u want to allow only certain file sizes
            return file && file.size <= 2000000;
          })
      });
```

Comment: I think you need  to include yup here: `file: yup.mixed()` otherwise mixed() is undefined..

Comment: Im allways getting File as undefined

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution for the new version 7

```js
 const fileSchema = yup.object().shape({
     file: yup.mixed().test("file", "You need to provide a file", (value) => {
       if (value.length > 0) {  
         return true;
       }
       return false;
       }),
   });
```