# How to use react-hook-form with react-dropzone?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-dropzone

I am trying to use react-hook-form with react dropzone to select image.

I have followed this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64783894/how-to-use-react-dropzone-with-react-hook-form) and used the [Conroller](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller).

Here is a wrapper from input fields.

```
type FieldWrapperProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  label: string;
  errorMessage?: string;
  className?: string;
};

export const FieldWrapper: FunctionComponent<FieldWrapperProps> = (props: FieldWrapperProps) => {
  const { children, label, errorMessage, className } = props;

  return (
    <div className={clsx(`mt-6 flex flex-col justify-start tracking-wide align-middle`, className)}>
      <label htmlFor={label} className="text-gray-light text-base  font-bold mb-2">
        {label}
      </label>
      {children}
      {errorMessage && <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-red-500 ">{errorMessage}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
type ImageFieldProps = {
  control: any;
};

export const ImageField: FunctionComponent<ImageFieldProps> = (props: ImageFieldProps) => {
  const { control } = props;
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: {
      'image/jpeg': [],
      'image/png': [],
    },
  });

  return (
    <Controller
      name="cover"
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FieldWrapper label="Cover Image">
          <section className="container">
            <div {...getRootProps({ className: 'dropzone' })}>
              <input
                {...getInputProps()}
                {...field}
                onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e.target.value)}
              />
              <p>Drag `n` drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
              <em>(Only *.jpeg and *.png images will be accepted)</em>
            </div>
          </section>
        </FieldWrapper>
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

I have used this component inside my form like so:

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormData>({
    mode: 'all',
    resolver: yupResolver(mySchema),
  });

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                 <ImageField control={control} />
    </form>
```

The form renders:

[image: render]

The field is not clickable and input field shows greyed out in the DOM.

[image: field]